# fundamental elliptic complex in Hodge theory

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, hodge-theory

I was trying to understand the following fundamental elliptic complex in Hodge theory (Here $M$ is a compact oriented four dimensional Riemannian manifold):

$$0\rightarrow \Omega^0(M) \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} \Omega^1(M) \stackrel{d^+}{\longrightarrow} \Omega^2_+(M)\rightarrow 0$$

How do we find the first cohomology group? i.e. decide $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ s.t. $d^+\omega=0 $ and $\omega$ is $L^2$-orthogonal to the image of $d$.

The answer is the harmonic 1-forms but I don't see why. Being $L^2$-orthogonal to image of $d$ means $\omega$ lies in the direct sum of harmonic 1-forms and image of $d^*$ by Hodge theory. but I don't see how the other condition served to eliminate the possibility of lying in image of $d^*$.

Comment: What is $d^+$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @ArcticChar The projection of $d\omega$ onto its self-dual part.

Comment: What self-dual part?  Did you forget an important condition on $M$?

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks! I did edit the question.

Comment: Do you also assume $M$ is compact?

Comment: @user10354138 yeah for the Hodge theory to be true. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Write $d : \Omega^1 \to \Omega^2$, since $\ker d \subset \ker d^+$, if the first cohomolgy group is the space of harmonic one form, then $\ker d = \ker d^+$. Is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Hodge decomposition
$$
\Omega^2(M)=\operatorname{im}(d\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2(M))\oplus\operatorname{im}(d^*\colon\Omega^3(M)\to\Omega^2(M))\oplus\ker(\Delta\colon\Omega^2(M)\to\Omega^2(M)).
$$
But
$$
\operatorname{im}(d^*\colon\Omega^3(M)\to\Omega^2(M))=\operatorname{im}(*d*\colon\Omega^3(M)\to\Omega^2(M))=\operatorname{im}(*d\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2(M)),$$
so for $\alpha\in\ker d^+$ we must have
$$
0=\lVert d^+\alpha\rVert_{L^2}^2
=\frac14\lVert d\alpha+*d\alpha\rVert_{L^2}^2
=\frac14(\lVert d\alpha\rVert_{L^2}^2+\lVert *d\alpha\rVert_{L^2}^2)
$$
i.e., we must have $d\alpha=0$.  In other words, $\ker(d^+\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2_+(M))=\ker(d\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2(M))$ and so the cohomology
$$
\frac{\ker(d^+\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2_+(M))}{\operatorname{im}(d\colon\Omega^0(M)\to\Omega^1(M))}=\frac{\ker(d\colon\Omega^1(M)\to\Omega^2(M))}{\operatorname{im}(d\colon\Omega^0(M)\to\Omega^1(M))}=H^1(M).
$$